# Intellij as merge tool does not correctly detect encoding

Tags: git, intellij-idea, merge

Intellij has a great merge tool. But when I use it from the command-line (as git 3-way merge tool), it does not detect the encodings correctly. The merge tool, when started given three Windows-1252 encoded files, will display a message at the top of the left and right pane, stating:

> Content was decoded with errors (using 'UTF-8' charset)

The project in question uses Windows-1252 encoding, so all Umlaute for example will be corrupt in a UTF-8 interpretation.

Is there any way to tell the diff-tool the encodings it should use or any other trick to fix this issue?

With all these conversion errors, it is unusable as a merge tool from the command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regrettably, there is no option to configure encoding for now.
There are feature requests for it, please feel free to vote:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-109396

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-112115

Comment: I have high hopes, Issue open since 8 years, 1 vote, respectively 7 years and 11 votes. Seems big projects are also big problems, such a simple feature, but it will probably never be done.